# How a company should manage their certificates for external developers?

Tags: xcode

I couldn't find this information on any official documentation or blog articles.
I work for a consultant company that create application for other companies, so keep in mind that I never develop apps for my company, but for those who's contracting us.

**The first thing is the certificate.**
Does the company that's contracting the consultant company that needs to create a certificate, export it (as p12 file) and send it to the other company that's development the application? Is this the right way?
If so, if the same company is contracting a second (third, fourth) consultant company, should they share the same certificated that was sent to the first consultant company with the others or they should create a new certificate for each one?

**The provisionng profiles**
I'm automating the build/release pipelines. So, for development environment, I have a provisioning profile to build the app for a specific set of devices.
On the release pipeline, I have to reassing the with a different provisioning profile. Can it be reassinged with the same certificate only changing the provisioning profile or do I need to have a different certicate?

Thanks